# VMware infrastructure conflict with Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, vmware-vcenter

I'm running both a standalone Tomcat server and the VMware infrastructure management services on a machine, and when stopping one the other one stops as well.

I think there's a port conflict somewhere, in e.g. the Tomcat control port. How can I change to ports on which VMware infra listens?

---

*Update*: I'm 99% sure that vmware infra uses Tomcat as well, since they react to the same messages. I'd like to change the ports used by VMware's Tomcat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conflict may be between the shutdown ports. VMware runs tomcat for the web access, and in my installation (VMware Server 2.0 on Ubuntu Linux) leaves the shutdown port at the default of 8005.

Try changing the port for the [shutdown command](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/server.html):

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
```

to

```
<Server port="9005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
```

for example. In my case, the path for the VMware `server.xml` was `/usr/lib/vmware/webAccess/tomcat/apache-tomcat-6.0.16/conf/server.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to change the port used by the VMWare instance specifically, or is it just to make sure that the two instances aren't conflicting?  Changing the VMWare port may have unexpected effects, as other VM components may be looking for a Tomcat instance on that port; it depends on your individual setup, I suppose.  Either way, you can change the port number in server.xml (Windows) or in the Tomcat startup script options under *nix.